# Drywall repair with electric cable

Tags: patching-drywall

I have cut small section of wall near ceiling so I can bore hole in top plate to run Romex cable (coming from ceiling) to new wall outlet.

I am done with wiring now and ready to patch wall. Usual practice to patch drywall cutout is to first screw in wood strips across the cutout section and then screw new drywall patch and secure it with wood strip with screw.

Given the Romex cable behind the wall now (*by the way this is remodeling wiring so I haven't stapled Romex with stud*), I want to avoid use of screw.

Can I use construction glue to stick wood strip with existing drywall and then new drywall patch ?

I could be just carefull when using screw to avoid the wire but I am kind of thinking for future. If someone pulls the wire , sharp tip of screw may damage its insulation.

Comment: You can use a screw that is shorter than the thickness of the wood but adhesive works.

Comment: Is it metal studs and wire running inside the stud?  Better use BX. If wooden stud, use stud finder and tip of screw will be inside stud, no hart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it concerns you that much just use a screw that isn't longer then the combined thickness of your drywall and wood strips. But why the hell would someone pull on a romex cable inside a finished wall? Your way overthinking it. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You cut a notch in the wood code requires 1-1/4” space for the cable so if you do not have a clear 1-1/4” a metal nail plate is required to bridge the gap.